# Resize screen of windows 10 using virtualbox in bootcamp windows

Tags: bootcamp, screen

I use Windows 10 using bootcamp on Macbook Pro (16, 2019). I installed VirtualBox (6.1.4), and installed windows 10 in it. Then, the screen of guest windows 10 is small. I installed the guest additions, but still screen option is like only up to 1280x... I use (two) 24 inch 4k monitor. How can I enlarge the screen size?

Comment: I just solved it in a different way: it turns out that vmware workstation player is free for non-commercial use, and after installing windows 10, I had to remove CD/DVD and Floppy, then add CD/DVD, then installed VMWare Tools without problem, and now the screen size is as what I want. (FYI, also using vmware-vdiskmanager.exe which is included in Virtual Disk Development Kit, I could make one single file from split files since some said it is more stable.)